# How to set up Openfire XMPP server?

Tags: sql-server, setup, xmpp

I have installed Openfire and Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2102 on my PC. I have made a database called openfire, conected to it, and have executed the script called **openfire_sqlserver.sql** from the Openfire Database directory. After these steps, I opened the Openfire Admin console in browser and selected Standard SQL from the database option, selected MS SQL Server option and entered **jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://Home/openfire;appName=jive** this.

On clicking next, it is giving an error of `unknown host name java.sql.SQLException: Unknown server host name '[host-name]'`.

***[this](http://dropbox.com/s/hqnzihghy3mxzl4/error%20-%20Copy.log)*** is the complete error log.
I did a tracert localhost and got the name Home. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please help me